# How to specify post template using WordPress REST API?

Tags: python, wordpress

I am creating WordPress posts using the REST API with Python.

I can't find any documentation or info on how to specify the post template that needs to be assigned to the created posts.

This is the format that I am using to specify the post data:

```
post = {
'date': new_time,
'title': title,
'content': '',
'status': 'publish'
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to specify the template the post should follow?

Comment: To see and specify `post data` or as wordpress call it `post attributes`, you could check out this: [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) which is the function responsible for creating a post in wordpress, which also tells you which data/attributes you could set for a post.

Comment: @Ruvee I have looked into it and managed to find out that post meta is passed by using 'post_meta': { 'wp_post_template': 'templatename.php'} but for some reason this is not working for me, I have tried messing around with it and used post_template instead of wp_post_template but still not luck.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I managed to find python-wordpress-xmlrpc’s documentation which states the way to specify the template that you would like a page to follow is:

```
post = {
'date': new_time,
'title': title,
'template': 'customtemplate.php',
'content': '',
'status': 'publish'
}
```

it's worth noting that you have to specify the file name for the template, not just the template name.

just going off the documentation, I am not sure if you can use 'template': for posts as it's listed under WordPressPage although it's derived from WordPressPost, so it might be possible.